# Allow delegate to work with inherited type

Tags: c#, inheritance, delegates

I'm not sure if I'm approaching this correctly. I did some searching, but couldn't find a good example.

I would like to have some objects inherit from a base type that includes a common method. I would like to pass in functions as delegates that would be called at the same time as the common method `DoWork`. But this delegate functions would internally work on properties only available in the child/inherited object.

Something like this:

```
public abstract class BaseModel
{
    public bool IsValid {get; set;}
    public delegate Task DelegateWork<in T>(T myObject)

    public virtual async Task DoWork<T>(DelegateWork<T> myDelegate)
    {
        // run some code
        await myDelegate(this);
    }
}
```

So, I would have an inherited class:

```
public interface IChild
{
    string ChildName {get; set;}
}
public class MyChild : BaseModel
{
    public string ChildName {get; set;}
}
```

Later in a service, I would add a function;

```
public class MyService
{
    private async Task CheckName<T>(<T> child) where T : BaseModel, IChild
    {
        if (child.ChildName == "BadData")
            child.IsValid = false;
    }

    public async Task<T> SpecialFunction<T>(T mySpecial) where T : BaseModel, IChild
    {
        // Do somestuff
        await mySpecial.DoWork(CheckName);
    }
}
```

This all looks good, except for `BaseModel.DoWork`, it doesn't like `this`.

How should I code it?

Comment: There's no reason to create your own delegate, just use `Func<T, Task>`

Comment: Still can't convert `this` to `T`.

Comment: You do that by simply removing `DoWork`.  it's a pointless method that accomplishes nothing, but makes things harder.  Just remove it and invoke the delegate when you want to call it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can educate me... what is the point of using generics in this scenario?  The delegate will always require an argument that derives from BaseModel, so you can do it like this:

```
public abstract class BaseModel
{
    public bool IsValid { get; set; }
    public delegate Task DelegateWork(BaseModel myObject);

    public virtual async Task DoWork(DelegateWork myDelegate)
    {
        // run some code
        await myDelegate(this);
    }
}

public interface IChild
{
    string ChildName { get; set; }
}
public class MyChild : BaseModel, IChild
{
    public string ChildName { get; set; }
}

public class MyService
{
    private async Task CheckName(BaseModel model)
    {
        var child = model as IChild;
        if (child != null && child.ChildName == "BadData")
            model.IsValid = false;
    }

    public async Task SpecialFunction(BaseModel mySpecial)
    {
        // Do somestuff
        await mySpecial.DoWork(CheckName);
    }
}
```

Comment: If I do `private async Task CheckName(IChild child)` the method doesn't understand what `IsValid` is. If I do `private async Task CheckName(BaseModel child)` the method doesn't know what `ChildName` is. If I do `private async Task CheckName(MyChild child)` I can't call `mySpecial.DoWork(CheckName)`, it doesn't fit the signature.

Comment: Oh, I see, you have the IsValid in the interface... that won't work. We need IsValid in the base class.

Comment: I see.  I edited my solution.  I guess you are using generics to get rid of the need to cast to an interface?

Comment: Thanks... I thought I tried the `model as IChild` cast, but I guess not in that syntax.

Comment: Hmm... well you can use this... but this not quite as good as what you were going for.  With this code you can call CheckName with an argument that doesn't implement IChild.  With a proper generic definition that would cause a compile time error, if I can figure it out....

Comment: Ah.. and that is exactly the problem.  BaseModel doesn't implement IChild so you can't pass it as an argument to myDelegate as `this`.  So.. working as intended.  Guess you have to do the cast.

Comment: Check out my other answer.

Answer (score 0):

Hey I think maybe I got it.  Just need to call it with `this as T`.

```
public abstract class BaseModel
{
    public bool IsValid { get; set; }
    public delegate Task DelegateWork<T>(T myObject) where T: BaseModel, IChild;

    public async Task DoWork<T>(DelegateWork<T> myDelegate) where T : BaseModel, IChild
    {
        // run some code
        await myDelegate(this as T);
    }
}

public interface IChild
{
    string ChildName { get; set; }
}

public class MyChild : BaseModel, IChild
{
    public string ChildName { get; set; }
}

public class MyService
{
    private async Task CheckName<T>(T model) where T: BaseModel, IChild
    {
        if (model.ChildName == "BadData")
            model.IsValid = false;
    }

    public async Task SpecialFunction<T>(T mySpecial) where T: BaseModel, IChild
    {
        // Do somestuff
        await mySpecial.DoWork<T>(CheckName);
    }
}
```

Comment: T isn't always going to implement IChild.

Comment: Right.  If it doesn't you should get compile time error due to the `where` portion of the declaration of `DelegateWork`.  This is intentional, right?  Because `CheckName` requires an argument that implements both `BaseModel` and `IChild`.